# What happened to the expected -ε- thematic vowel in present active indicative 1 p sg and 3 p pl?

Tags: grammar-identification, conjugation, homeric-greek

I am trying to understand how Greek verbs are formed, having just begun learning their formation in present active indicative. The model verb used is λύω, which I understand to be formed as such:

| singularis |  |  | dualis |  | pluralis |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st | 2nd | 3rd | 2nd | 3rd | 1st | 2nd | 3rd |
| λύ-∅-ω | λύ-ε-ις | λύ-ε-ι | λύ-ε-τον | λύ-ε-τον | λύ-ο-μεν | λύ-ε-τε | λυ-ο-υσι |

The explanations I have found for the thematic vowel include:

> **796.** The thematic verbs are so named because in a majority of their forms the personal ending (819–821) is preceded by <sup>ο</sup>⁄<sub>ε</sub> (*ο* before *μ* or *ν*, or in the optative mode, otherwise *ε*), which is called the *thematic* vowel. Thus, λυ<sup>ο</sup>⁄<sub>ε</sub> (λύω) is called the *theme*, to which the personal endings (819–821) are attached.
> ―Wright/Pharr: *Homeric Greek*

Further, in Shelmerdine:

> You’ll notice that all the present active verb forms contain some form of an **o** or **e** vowel:

| Singular |  |  |  | Plural |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st | (I) | -ω | o | (we) | -ο-μεν | o |
| 2nd | (you) | -εις | e | (you) | -ε-τε | e |
| 3rd | (he) | -ει | e | (they) | -ουσῐ | o |

> This is the *thematic vowel*, which regularly appears in certain forms as an **e**, in others as an **o**. We can describe a *thematic verb* like λύω as consisting of three parts: stem, thematic vowel, and personal ending.
> ―Shelmerdine, C. W.: *L. A. Wilding’s Greek for Beginners*, Focus Publishing / R. Pullins Co., Newburyport, 2001, pp. 6f.

In the following table, she lists the verb forms as λύ-ω, λύ-εις, λύ-ει, λύ-ο-μεν, λύ-ε-τε, λύ-ουσῐ(ν), only using a hyphen to show the thematic vowel for the plurals. None of these explanations therefore leave me with a proper understanding of what is going on. Based off of Wright/Pharr, I would have expected 1st person singular to be -ε-ω and 3rd person plural to be -ε-υσῐ(ν), as their explanation specifies that it is -ε- except before -μ and -ν (which yields an -ο-). Is there a (historical) linguistic explanation for why these two forms apparently do not follow the rules explained by Wright and Pharr? Or am I missing something obvious? (In which case I apologise!)

Comment: The underlying idea in the first chart is good, but doesn't account for other sound changes that occurred. *An Introduction to Ancient Greek*, by C. A. E.  Lusching, p 32, puts it this way: "Note that the thematic vowel has been absorbed in the long endings, -ω, -εις, -ει, -ουσι.  Otherwise it can be seen quite clearly as an element used to join the endings to the stem.

This explanation is a compromise approach.   He is saying: "for endings starting with long vowels, just memorize them; but for endings beginning with short vowels, here is a pattern you can use and that may help later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Proto-Indo-European, an alternation between **e* and **o* is common (sometimes also including lengthened **ē* and **ō*, or zero (the vowel disappearing)). This alternation is commonly called "ablaut", though some people prefer the Greek equivalent "apophony", and happens in both roots and suffixes.

For example, compare πατ**έ**ρα, ἀπάτ**ο**ρα, πατ**ή**ρ, ἀπάτ**ω**ρ, and πατρός. All of these come from the same root, but the vowel appearing in that root changes depending on the form. Similarly, λ**έ**γω~λ**ό**γος, λ**ε**ίπειν~λέλ**ο**ιπα~λιπεῖν, γ**έ**νος~γ**ό**νος~γίγνομαι, and so on. Greek has a lot of reflexes of this.

The exact details aren't completely understood, but for whatever reason, the 1S (maybe), 1P, and 3P forms take **o* as their thematic vowel, while the others take **e*. Pharr suggests a phonetic motivation, which makes sense to me: the ancestor of the 3P form has an **n* in it (compare Latin *-nt*), and **ons* regularly becomes ουσ in Attic but οισ in Aeolic (compare second declension acc pl)—which is exactly what we see in the 3P ending (Sappho 2 αἰ δ' ἄηται /
μέλλιχα **πνέοισιν** "and the breezes gently blow").

The important part to remember, though, is that by Classical times, **that's just how it is**. Synchronically, there's no *n* in the 3P ending in Attic, and Greek-speakers in general almost certainly didn't think in terms of ablaut grades. They just knew those were the forms they'd inherited, and thus what they used.

Comment: Doric actually has -onti in 3rd pl. present active, even in "Classical times" (whatever that means).

Comment: @fdb Fair, I should clarify that I mean in Attic there (and also Ionic and Aeolic I suppose). By "Classical times" I mean broadly the period from the introduction of alphabetic writing to, say the first couple centuries or so—the period that most "ancient Greek" literature comes from.

Answer (score 3):

This is a basic Indo-European phenomenon called “ablaut”: the fluctuation between e and o in parallel forms. We have it also in legō (with e) vs logos (with o in the root syllable). In the personal endings of the present paradigm of the thematic verbs we have  e in lueis, luei, luete, and the dual forms, but o in lu-ō, lu-o-men and lu-o-nsi > luousi.

Comment: Does that mean there was an older form where the expected form vowel existed?

Comment: The expected thematic vowel exists in all these forms except for 1st sing, where it is swallowed by the following ending.